# How can i create JavaScript test cases for functional testing

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-web-api2, functional-testing, postman

Recently I have developed a website, for which I want to do functional testing.My API returns data in form of JSON. I heard about Newman, but not sure about it.Basically I want to validate for property and its value i.e key-value pair. 
Which tool will be best? Can anyone tell me steps,as testing is new for me.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: At work we just write an xunit test suite that makes HTTP requests and asserts on the responses. Works well enough.